# Если после имени домена поставить знак вопроса - то открывается главная страница

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, поисковые-системы, индексация, http-status-code-301

Если после имени домена поставить знак вопроса - то открывается главная страница.
Так же после знака вопроса можно ставить любые знаки, все равно открывается главная страница.пример `site.ru/?domain=www.ivanovokredit.ru` Как сделать чтобы пользователь в этом случае отправлялся на страницу 404?

Comment: Появилась такая же проблема при добавлении знака # (дальше можно подставлять что угодно, открывается главная),-  яндекс вебмастер видит их как клоны главной страницы, как можно отсечь и перенаправить на страницу 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знак `?` означает передачу параметров через `GET` запрос. Все, что идет после `?`, включая сам `?` - это **QUERY_STRING**

Отсечь можно, например, вот так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /404.php? [L,R=404]
```

Только учтите, что это может нарушить функционал движка Вашего сайта. Возможно, `RewriteCond` понадобится уточнить, для отмены срабатывания при некоторых параметрах